# Is it possible to check if given exception_ptr instance owns an exception of certain type?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have an `std::exception_ptr` instance. I need to check if underlying exception is of certain type (and ideally get access to it). It can be done this way:

```
std::exception_ptr p = ...;
try
{
    std::rethrow_exception(p);
}
catch(MyType const& x)
{
    ...
}
catch(...)
{
    // do smth else
}
```

Is there a better way?

Is there a guarantee `std::rethrow_exception` isn't going to copy underlying exception leading to problems like throwing `std::bad_alloc` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::rethrow_exception` is the only way to retreive underlying exception object, so it must be used. Assuming that every exception inherits from `std::exception` you could make 'dynamic_cast' if-else chain. I've tried it with dummy exceptions and it works. If it is better - it's matter of taste. In this approach it is easier to have some shared context or do two cases or do something in case of being two types.

More interesting part of your question was about copying object - according to C++ reference `std::exception_ptr` "is a shared pointer-like type", so no copying should happen. Although, I've made simple test cases and it does get copied in Visual Studio 2017. It works fine in GCC. I don't have information about other compilers.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <exception>

class A :public std::exception
{
public: 
};


class B :public std::exception
{
public:
    virtual const char* what() const
    {
        return "B";
    }
    B() { printf("Created B at %X\n", this); }
    B(const B& b) { printf("Copied B from %X at %X\n", &b, this); } // make it copyable
    B& operator=(const B& b) { printf("Copied B from %X at %X\n", &b, this); return *this;}; // make it copyable
    B(const B&& b) { printf("Moved B from %X at %X\n", &b, this); } // make it movable

};

class C : public B
{
public:
    int q;

    C(int qq) { q = qq; printf("Created C at %X with q=%d\n", this, q); }
    C(const C& c) :B(c) { q = c.q; printf("Copied C from %X at %X\n", &c, this); } // make it copyable
    C& operator=(const C& c) { q = c.q; printf("Copied C from %X at %X\n", &c, this); return *this; }; // make it copyable
    C(const C&& c):B(std::move(c)) { q = std::move(c.q); printf("Moved C from %X at %X\n", &c, this); } // make it movable
};

int main()
{
    // Check does rethrow_exception copies underlying object
    try
    {
        B b; // B created
        throw std::move(b);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        auto p = std::current_exception();
        try
        {
            std::rethrow_exception(std::move(p));
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            auto p = std::current_exception();
            try
            {
                std::rethrow_exception(p);
            }
            catch (B& b) // refered to last copy
            {
                printf("done with B at %X\n", &b);
            }
        }
    }


    printf("\n");
    // Try with dynamic_cast
    try {
        C c(12);
        throw std::move(c);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        printf("Caught something\n");
        auto p = std::current_exception();
        try {
            std::rethrow_exception(p);
        }
        catch (std::exception& ex)
        {
            printf("Caught ex\n");
            if (A* a = dynamic_cast<A*>(&ex))
                printf("ex is A\n");
            if (B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(&ex))
                printf("ex is B\n");
            if (C* c = dynamic_cast<C*>(&ex))
                printf("ex is also C with q=%d\n", c->q);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm... Are you [sure](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UyBipjunBORHxi92) about copying? In any case -- I was looking for assurances from standard, if one compiler implements it this way, it doesn't mean others will do the same.

Comment: It seems that you're correct about `rethrow_exception` being the only way to access exception, but your own code sample shows that copy/move doesn't happen (at least with gcc). If you fix it -- I'll accept your answer

Comment: I've stated that no copying should happed, but unfortunately it does in VS2017 and GCC works fine. Is it ok?

Comment: Another thing I noticed -- `std::exception_ptr` is not moveable in MSVC 2015. There is a `shared_ptr` under the hood -- you copy it every time `exception_ptr` is coped.